# C++20 coroutines don't allow computed goto's? (GNU label extension)

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++20, c++-coroutine

I just finished writing my JSON parser using computed gotos and coroutines. I thought this was a match made in heaven as it allows me to write the most beautiful spaghetti code. But it turns out, compiler support is very limited as of 2023. I was in good hopes as my code compiles fine in gcc which is actually all I care about. But then I found out that the gcc fork that is used by my microcontroller vendor has trouble making it work. In fact it compiles fine in gcc trunk but not in gcc 12.2 (what is the difference?). For my purposes I need it to work in xtensa gcc 12.2 and risc-v gcc 12.2. Here's the code in question:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAbBqkAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XoKdQ1N2a2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQma27Ig/io%2B9gmGgCC65vbmHsHaMQLjiFnF9dmGwxbXrv7bkGxGCwAA%2BgA3PCYADu7yuNx%2BdwebgIXkS9Dhn2%2Bv3%2BB2OmFUy0SBExCJx9wB9WITAAnqSrkCvA4dspniw8Ep9lZ4QyCMQmQQWfUlMQdiAdokvBFaHhkDtjiAUCQXsFMKCEIZ0BiDqzUOzOWtsHsAOzc65XHaWnZeVJGCVsjlqgg0xIUtYAETFIF1%2BswXI%2BHytOwAfsphdEIDMTWag0GsEDUDTI/6LVaTMb3QGMynzZdGczLtCmIQmNKKabA1amF4iDsmEXCKDiJgmOgk1GALRnHYRVCeaP24IEKgQcxmevFghNlttsBgEwAVjcDDHMy5O2bqOIDB2VDEBosJszqct1drE8bChtroY6AgCqVzxrqvVmu1bh9ju7Gtv9Cj6asbMTzrGtUDrBsp2bK82EjHYu0NHZwVQPB0GjdNMzWM10JzD580FT8lDQ4CHyBEEIShaEJSBcFQRw4CzzA4BMEg5jFgYUFUAibRMAcWD4KNMNiBFAdNzY6NBJFRUqDZUFEgdJQIAAKgIBAOTXbNMKPHMgwYnZgjSMRQSvBQbzvKMGFQAkiUFfj5QIdBFWM0zQRCcFohE1jtzQjTD2w%2BjQN3YJDKc1xYIsqzMGJODuxI69XFBMQixpBQPK3HcAOwzS/MuHSAovKc%2BUMBR%2BGIFg%2BO7QtJ1LehUrYjKfK0/za1E7cIWQsyBzkocRzHFqdyQlC50XZdV3XbLctrLwGB/LVMHQUEIuJdJYPq49rh8gMrgITAWHRJhtuRZ0b1Ye4ABVMV0p5UHKhCJPcjLgIG9BFJ2NBBGCLx9vSdU%2BwAaweT1zFiIH0AEP1MM2nKrTe15PuqH7UH%2B/ZAbMYHUdbebOO4hxQUIHa6Khy1gFQWtFJhj6voEBHfoJoMusEHqzDMUIScHQQ5qGpcVyZtcIZ5S4MY4rieKnPGWBASG6eBBnRyZgB1Ehfo5%2BcudGvnc1BkIJf5qXutlsxNcwTmRp52nodQac0pwoDcyHHYWGLBgVorYC7tFFgXXDUVkde5UASHM5k3V7KODmWhOAXXg/A4LRSFQTg3Gsax5QWJYKS%2BHhSAITRQ7mX6QC%2BAA6AAOSRjViLgAE4FwXY0F2LhdK6Z/ROEkKOc7jzheAUEAEmzmPQ9IOBYCQN6Sodn5MHISg0F2uhoh72BZ8SefiAASQc4hwTWMwO2AZBkC4JmElQJaBB7jgOw7Y5kdMSxrDMDQ4LlsRaDggB5BRB4gZfV43kBgAKGYIkBQCASZxzPgwC%2BV8b4ejvlYSwj9n6vw/l/OYP89Qr3oOvBymATI72AI/L4GhH7FwgdUaB197K3yTogp%2BHYX60Dfh2T%2B39f7YP/sAI%2BZhyHpEobA908CH70MYcw1hMw5hzUICQFCegDBGH/kIyw%2Bg8AREXpGMOEd24D07hwDwDBx6GGWDsAAahRdyEBcDSO9hnKMkgAD0XBI5ZxzhI0gCAZz9EjKQfOqNC41wXFwYuawpDBLWJIeuC4W4cDbqQaOsd44cG7r3FxA90EwCgBkiAo9MGr2nhgue2CAFAKYCAsBBBSBYEhMsMxMJ343k4JnGgtBtpCUoBEDuEQgrEBpI03gXTmA9PfsLBwfTSCzzYIId%2BDBaC9J0VgCewBxDzLwM2BweA3IX1jgSHiNYVixyHJUDuMoIjUh6R4LAHc%2BR4HFtwQeVADCANqdCepjAxn8EECIMQ7ApAyEEIoFQ6gdG6FaPI4wtCbAnPUXMU%2BFDOAwOoXAiFSCGEoJYV/NoIt0guFvCMFopBAiqimP0VouQ0gCDxTkFI5KGCTD6DEMYlQsUCE6MMTwzQBhMvWSyoY3QiX0oGLyylYxeV0pKCSuYChU7LFmNE5x8TeCJJ2KoYusQOyxEkDsfecoIB8imr9KMlj8BEBsSEmYvB%2B5aDcR41sXi84SA0AkcOMTeDizWMXQuldJCV1iMaLgxpjRmEkGYYuobYhxI7ok5JfdXFDyyUgF4koKkUAKVg6IoQTqcBVWqjVWqD47CPoXMwvApEmtka0D5whRDiF%2BZWgFagO4gtINCakiQ%2BmaI4PKyNnB341iTTsVAVBlWqvVZq7VOxdX8gYAaidHhCn3VsRa1xcwbVYBiN451sTxYV0LhoBcGgd7FyZnXP1XBfkKt0dG1JVr7VmC4IXP1JDJAaG9UG8uXxolrG0Qkru17v7xqVPOsgKb2H9C4c3KpspMDPNedHJpdBWk9wgB0nRAz6hzMzmhoZIz%2B6ZwmYwAg0zZkdwWYYJZ%2BzeD4DWY4TZHcdnID2WMw5zrY4nLOTSC5FGs7AluTwOYDymBPIorB95sgvk1ukHWpQDbgUF30GRlAEKVFqPgDCyB/DEWCORSItFrDMXcr8BAVwwqCW3jFdMUl1LqgmbJdUczJL9PVFZY0dloxHMdFFfy8VDLbBCtc/i8YDR7MMsldKn5Hau06KVdm0dea5SFrMBOqxJq9iLr/W43xxoS6qurrEYuGguDxB3saaJsSL1RtsCky1udonFojVF391W3FuSEtiyQQA%3D)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <coroutine>
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <array>

struct Promise;

struct Parser : public std::coroutine_handle<Promise> {

    using promise_type = ::Promise;

    ~Parser() {
        destroy();
    }
};

struct Awaitable {
    auto await_ready() -> bool { printf("await_ready!\n"); return false; }
    auto await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<Promise> handle) {}
    auto await_resume() -> void {};
};

struct Promise {
    std::string_view pstrv_;

    auto get_return_object() -> Parser { return {Parser::from_promise(*this)}; };
    auto initial_suspend() noexcept -> std::suspend_never { return {}; }
    auto final_suspend() noexcept -> std::suspend_always { return {}; }
    auto await_transform() -> Awaitable { return{}; }
    auto return_void() { printf("return void!\n"); }
    auto unhandled_exception() {}
};

template <typename T>
auto coro() -> Parser {
    void* continuation_hook = &&done;

    continuation_hook = &&add_object_item;

    goto *continuation_hook;

    printf("Not printed!\n");

add_object_item:

    printf("Worked!\n");

done:

    printf("done!\n");

    co_return;
}

int main() {
    Parser myparser = coro<int>();
}
```

For gcc 12.2 I get this error:

```
<source>:40:23: warning: storing the address of local variable 'add_object_item' in '*frame_ptr.coro<int>()::_Z4coroIiE6Parserv.Frame::continuation_hook_1_2' [-Wdangling-pointer=]
   40 |     continuation_hook = &&add_object_item;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:46:1: note: 'add_object_item' declared here
   46 | add_object_item:
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:46:1: note: 'frame_ptr' declared here
```

Interestingly clang (trunk) braces against computed gotos in coroutines altogether:

```
<source>:38:31: error: the GNU address of label extension is not allowed in coroutines.
    void* continuation_hook = &&done;
                              ^
<source>:40:25: error: the GNU address of label extension is not allowed in coroutines.
    continuation_hook = &&add_object_item;
                        ^
```

So after all it seems that computed goto's are not considered for coroutines even though they would combine pretty well (e.g. fast parsers). I would totally root for standardised computed goto's at this point. In any case, my view is now glazing to different lands forcibly as I don't want to drop this project.

Is there an equally fast and more portable alternative?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You're talking about the interaction between a GCC-created feature and a newly implemented feature of the language. Is it really surprising that maybe they didn't work out all of the interactions between the newly implemented language feature and this other thing they also allowed?

Comment: Don't expect Clang support. https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56436 - short of gettig computed gotos standardized

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Interesting this guy basically had the same problem as I. I think they should finally standardize it because computed gotos will never go away and are perfect for niche use cases. The only thing we need is them to be more safe.

Comment: Implementation divergence makes standardisation less likely, I think.